How to deal with overlapping structural variants?
I have a VCF file with structural variations that were predicted by smoove but it contains many overlapping structural variations, such as this.
NC_037357.1 18687367    1070    N   <DUP>   1013.36 PASS    SVTYPE=DUP;SVLEN=43503;END=18730870;STRANDS=-+:107;IMPRECISE;CIPOS=-148,79;CIEND=-149,45;CIPOS95=-29,29;CIEND95=-124,45;SU=107;PE=107;SR=0;SNAME=DC62:89,DC70:128,DC32:82,DC60:129,DC29:79;ALG=SUM;AN=108;AC=103    GT:GQ:SQ:GL:DP:RO:AO:QR:QA:RS:AS:ASC:RP:AP:AB
NC_037357.1 18687373    1069    N   <DUP>   737.99  PASS    SVTYPE=DUP;SVLEN=43162;END=18730535;STRANDS=-+:1205;IMPRECISE;CIPOS=-408,102;CIEND=-58,352;CIPOS95=-28,28;CIEND95=-29,29;SU=1205;PE=1205;SR=0;SNAME=DC99:114,DC78:55,DC74:127,DC111:118,DC77:140,DC17:73,DC116:76,DC44:83,DC11:93,DC66:145,DC2:85,DC94:101,DC10:64,DC45:85,DC113:91,DC63:89,DC103:137,DC68:120,DC8:62,DC36:69,DC50:145,DC43:58,DC87:131,DC67:118,DC1:84,DC57:69,DC100:54,DC48:175,DC3:73,DC72:169,DC15:34,DC16:92,DC81:55,DC95:124,DC64:81,DC88:123,DC65:153,DC6:45,DC54:116,DC112:141,DC12:62,DC97:89,DC56:110,DC28:122;ALG=SUM;AN=108;AC=52   GT:GQ:SQ:GL:DP:RO:AO:QR:QA:RS:AS:ASC:RP:AP:AB
NC_037357.1 18687376    1071    N   <DUP>   894.97  PASS    SVTYPE=DUP;SVLEN=43368;END=18730744;STRANDS=-+:77;IMPRECISE;CIPOS=-76,46;CIEND=-20,81;CIPOS95=-6,6;CIEND95=-4,4;SU=77;PE=77;SR=0;SNAME=DC104:118,DC5:78,DC82:83;ALG=PROD;AN=108;AC=103  GT:GQ:SQ:GL:DP:RO:AO:QR:QA:RS:AS:ASC:RP:AP:AB
NC_037357.1 18688294    1073    N   <DUP>   807.48  PASS    SVTYPE=DUP;SVLEN=43188;END=18731482;STRANDS=-+:175;IMPRECISE;CIPOS=-420,133;CIEND=-62,474;CIPOS95=-188,133;CIEND95=-62,90;SU=175;PE=175;SR=0;SNAME=DC82:84,DC60:131,DC12:63,DC65:155,DC5:80,DC1:85,DC116:77,DC56:112,DC28:124,DC95:126,DC97:90,DC3:76,DC66:147,DC32:83,DC72:171,DC6:46,DC63:90,DC44:84;ALG=SUM;AN=108;AC=104    GT:GQ:SQ:GL:DP:RO:AO:QR:QA:RS:AS:ASC:RP:AP:AB
NC_037357.1 18688300    1074    N   <DUP>   765.23  PASS    SVTYPE=DUP;SVLEN=43408;END=18731708;STRANDS=-+:17;IMPRECISE;CIPOS=-78,49;CIEND=-50,204;CIPOS95=-18,18;CIEND95=-26,26;SU=17;PE=17;SR=0;SNAME=DC94:102;ALG=PROD;AN=108;AC=107 GT:GQ:SQ:GL:DP:RO:AO:QR:QA:RS:AS:ASC:RP:AP:AB
NC_037357.1 18688437    1075    N   <DUP>   464.57  PASS    SVTYPE=DUP;SVLEN=43511;END=18731948;STRANDS=-+:5;IMPRECISE;CIPOS=-25,41;CIEND=-50,30;CIPOS95=-11,11;CIEND95=-7,7;SU=5;PE=5;SR=0;SNAME=DC17:75;ALG=PROD;AN=108;AC=53 GT:GQ:SQ:GL:DP:RO:AO:QR:QA:RS:AS:ASC:RP:AP:AB
NC_037357.1 18688885    1072    N   <DUP>   1085.88 PASS    SVTYPE=DUP;SVLEN=43076;END=18731961;STRANDS=-+:419;IMPRECISE;CIPOS=-512,66;CIEND=-119,462;CIPOS95=-223,66;CIEND95=-66,66;SU=419;PE=419;SR=0;SNAME=DC7:53,DC10:65,DC104:121,DC111:120,DC87:132,DC103:139,DC94:103,DC100:56,DC36:71,DC88:126,DC50:147,DC43:60,DC95:127,DC67:121,DC112:143,DC64:82,DC29:80,DC54:118,DC77:142,DC16:94,DC72:172,DC70:130,DC78:57,DC45:86,DC74:128,DC11:94,DC113:94,DC48:176,DC2:87,DC60:132;ALG=SUM;AN=108;AC=60 GT:GQ:SQ:GL:DP:RO:AO:QR:QA:RS:AS:ASC:RP:AP:AB
NC_037357.1 18689062    1335    N   <INV>   1938.59 PASS    SVTYPE=INV;SVLEN=1182;END=18690244;STRANDS=++:810,--:4;IMPRECISE;CIPOS=-51,536;CIEND=-58,527;CIPOS95=-51,55;CIEND95=-58,74;SU=814;PE=814;SR=0;SNAME=DC94:95_1,DC65:148_1,DC97:84_1,DC2:81_1,DC112:136,DC11:88_1,DC5:73_1,DC81:51_1,DC100:50_1,DC48:170_1,DC72:164_1,DC6:39_1,DC43:53_1,DC113:86,DC36:64_1,DC67:113_1,DC116:70_1,DC3:69_1,DC54:111_1,DC1:79_1,DC66:140_1,DC95:119_1,DC103:132_1,DC15:30_1,DC99:109_1,DC50:140_1,DC57:65_1,DC60:124_1,DC68:115_1,DC77:134_1,DC29:74_1,DC62:84,DC64:75_1,DC88:118_1,DC10:60_1,DC74:121_1,DC63:83_1,DC8:57_1,DC28:117_1,DC16:87_1,DC32:76_1,DC82:78_1,DC111:113_1,DC104:113_1,DC78:50_1,DC45:79_1,DC44:78_1,DC56:105_1,DC87:126_1;ALG=SUM;AN=108;AC=54  GT:GQ:SQ:GL:DP:RO:AO:QR:QA:RS:AS:ASC:RP:AP:AB
NC_037357.1 18692165    1077    N   <DUP>   90.12   PASS    SVTYPE=DUP;SVLEN=43221;END=18735386;STRANDS=-+:33;IMPRECISE;CIPOS=-174,49;CIEND=-35,302;CIPOS95=-9,9;CIEND95=-13,13;SU=33;PE=33;SR=0;SNAME=DC16:96,DC56:114,DC28:126,DC57:72,DC54:120;ALG=PROD;AN=108;AC=8  GT:GQ:SQ:GL:DP:RO:AO:QR:QA:RS:AS:ASC:RP:AP:AB
NC_037357.1 18693751    1078    N   <DUP>   28.27   PASS    SVTYPE=DUP;SVLEN=43123;END=18736874;STRANDS=-+:19;IMPRECISE;CIPOS=-339,49;CIEND=-41,337;CIPOS95=-22,22;CIEND95=-34,34;SU=19;PE=19;SR=0;SNAME=DC87:134,DC63:92,DC9:118,DC16:97;ALG=PROD;AN=108;AC=6  GT:GQ:SQ:GL:DP:RO:AO:QR:QA:RS:AS:ASC:RP:AP:AB
NC_037357.1 18694379    1079    N   <DUP>   37.56   PASS    SVTYPE=DUP;SVLEN=43057;END=18737436;STRANDS=-+:5;CIPOS=-10,9;CIEND=-10,9;CIPOS95=0,0;CIEND95=0,0;SU=5;PE=0;SR=5;SNAME=DC2:89;ALG=PROD;AN=108;AC=1   GT:GQ:SQ:GL:DP:RO:AO:QR:QA:RS:AS:ASC:RP:AP:AB


I want to use high-quality structural variations for eQTL mapping, so I need to retain the true positive SVs. However, there are many overlapping SVs that may be different types. Are there any false positives among them?
I would appreciate any tips for dealing with this situation.
